# Slice a 3D object/ scene into multiple planes

Tags: rendering, scene

I want to slice a scene into multiple planes. For example, if I have a rgbd image, the points closest to the camera gets snapped in the first plane and so on.
Basically, I want to slice a 3D scene into planes based on distance from the camera.

I initially thought of boolean modifiers, but that is not what I want. I am a beginner and I am clueless how to proceed further.[image: Multiplanar camera] The image depicts how I want to slice my scene depending on distance from camera in Blender.
Please help me how to start.
P.S: 1 method I found is to snap points to nearest planes and render only the points that are snapped on the plane. But, I don't know how to proceed with this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi :). I'd look into camera's minimum clipping distance. perhaps worth a try ;)

Comment: Hi, @JachymMichal thank you for your answer. But can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Do you want each plane to have individual _whole_ elements (ex: bike, tree, road), or do you want the planes to take a "cross section" of whatever they're displaying (ex: the inside of the tree)?

Comment: You could just render each individual slice of the scene separately and then reimport them as image sequences on planes that you can manipulate freely.

Comment: Create separate *View Layers* for each section you want to render and sort the objects into *Collections* corresponding to each desired depth step

Comment: Hi @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, my question was how to make the slices from a composite image. Can you help me regarding this?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Hi, I only want the whole elements present in a plane that are at a specific distance from the camera.